# Charboost Ad not dispalying in my app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, chartboost

I am integrating chart boost Ad into my iOS app. But it is not displaying any Ad.
I used the following code in 'applicationDidBecomeActive' method, to display the chart boost.

```
 Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];
cb.appId = "YOUR_CHARTBOOST_APP_ID";
cb.appSignature = "YOUR_CHARTBOOST_APP_SIGNATURE";
// Begin a user session
[cb startSession];
// Show an interstitial
[cb showInterstitial];
```

What is the problem with this? Is there anything else that I have to do?

Thanking You in Advance

Comment: YOUR_CHARTBOOST_APP_ID did you used this string only or actually replaced it with app id from chartboost ?

Comment: The appID and appSignature correctly replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer following links:-

https://help.chartboost.com/downloads/ios

https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples

The second link contains example code too, so you can refer that, and your code just need to be written in appdelegate file with proper chartboost_id and chartboost_secret. [cb showInterstitial] should be in the controller you want to display ads.

Comment: If it helped you, you can accept the answer or give me positive points.

Answer (score -1):

Is it giving you any error message ? You don't want to show us your `appId` and `appSignature` or you are assigning the same `appId` and `appSignature`.
If you have not created them yet please go through this [link](https://dashboard.chartboost.com/)

1.Create an account.
 2.Choose Apps tab then Add App

[image]

3.Fill all fields.

[image]

After that use that `appId` and `appSignature` in your code. You will able to show `Interstitial` popup.

If you want to show `More Apps` list too then you will have to add a `Campaigns`.
Select  `Campaigns` tab then add `Campaigns` > `Publish in Network` and fill the detail. After that edit your app choose `More App Page` fill the added `Campaigns` name in that device and click on save. Now you can use `[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showMoreApps];` method too.

**Note: If you are testing it on simulator and app is not live your Chartboost's app's test mode should be enabled.**